# Joining tables while choosing which one a specific column pulls from

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb, subquery, mariadb-10.4

EDIT: I'm on version 10.4.11-MariaDB. Here is some code to create the pictured tables

```
CREATE TABLE cats (
  c_id        INT            PRIMARY KEY   AUTO_INCREMENT,
  c_name      VARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL      UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE stock (
  p_id         INT            PRIMARY KEY   AUTO_INCREMENT,
  c_id        INT            NOT NULL,
  level         DECIMAL(10,2)  NOT NULL,
  rating   DECIMAL(10,2)  NOT NULL      DEFAULT 0.00
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
  p_id         INT            NOT NULL,
  sales           INT            NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO cats (c_id, c_name) VALUES
(1, 'Boat'),
(2, 'Plane'),
(3, 'Car'), 
(4, 'Bike');

INSERT INTO stock (p_id, c_id, level, rating) VALUES
(1, 1, 145.65, 41),
(2, 1, 915.06, 49),
(3, 1, 981.36, 64),
(4, 1, 727.81, 29),
(5, 2, 678.19, 51),
(6, 2, 808.13, 43),
(7, 2, 711.10, 17),
(8, 3, 503.34, 92),
(9, 4, 292.41, 19),
(10, 4, 15.67, 36);


INSERT INTO orders (p_id, sales) VALUES
(1, 2),
(2, 4),
(9, 4),
(3, 2),
(8, 4),
(6, 3),
(2, 1),
(10, 2),
(8, 3),
(1, 4);
```

---

I'm going to try and be really thorough with this since I've already had this question closed before, so please let me know if I need to provide any additional information. I'll start with three sample tables that are representative of the data I'm working with, named `cats`, `stock`, and `orders` (all lowercase, if it matters).

[image]

The basic idea is that each `p_id` has an associated `rating`, `level`, and `sales` value, and `p_id` values can be categorized by their shared `c_id`. Each `p_id` in `stock` is unique and belongs to only one `c_id`. My goal is to produce a table that performs some simple calculations on aggregations of the `rating`, `level`, and `sales` columns, grouped by `c_name`. I've color coded each `p_id` by what `c_id` they belong to to hopefully make things easier to interpret. Below is an example of the table that I would like to produce:

[image]

EDIT: min rating for Car should be 92, not 8

As you can see, I want to select four columns:

- Every value in `c_name`
- The amount of `p_id` values that share the `c_id` corresponding to `c_name`
- The minimum `rating` of any `p_id` contained within each category
- The average `level` of all `p_id` values within each category
- The combined amount of `sales` for all `p_id` values within each category

I'd also like to have a row at the bottom with these same calculations taken for the entire population of `p_id` values, ignoring categories. That is, a row with the sum of `# of P_id's`, the minimum value of `min rating`, the average of `avg level`, and the sum of `# of sales`. Note that `orders`does not include every `p_id` in `stock`, and some `p_id` values are repeated; it's important that the middle three rows include each and every `p_id` only once, regardless of how many times they appear in `orders`. Likewise, the final column must sum the sales of the `p_id` values present and group them by category.

I wrote this query to try and produce this:

```
SELECT c_name, COUNT(p_id), MIN(rating), FORMAT(AVG(level),2), (SELECT SUM(sales) FROM orders JOIN stock USING(p_id))

FROM stock

JOIN cats USING(c_id)

GROUP BY c_name ASC WITH ROLLUP
```

This produces almost exactly what I want, except for an issue with the final column, where it simply shows the total amount of sales for all `p_id` values combined, regardless of category. I wanted to calculate this column with a subquery in the SELECT statement, as if I instead LEFT JOIN `orders` with `stock` after JOINing `stock` with `cats`, *every* column would perform their calculations based on only the `p_id` values found within `orders`. My thinking was to avoid this by simply selecting the values I need for the final column that I need in a subquery, but I'm struggling to figure out how I can group my results by category_id when the map from `product_id` to `category_id` only exists within `stock`.

In essence, I think my problem boils down to not knowing how I can have my middle three columns aggregate data based on the `p_id` column in `stock` while making sure the last column only takes from `orders`. Can anyone offer me advice?

Please let me know if I need to be more specific.

Comment: Replace your pictures of source data and provide CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts instead. And specify your MySQL version.

Comment: I've added scripts to the top. @Akina

Comment: Check your expected results. Min rating for Car should be 92 and # of sales for Bike should be 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your sample data this will work:

```
SELECT c.c_name, t.`# of p_ids`, t.`min rating`, t.`avg level`,
       COALESCE(
         SUM(o.sales),
         (SELECT SUM(sales) FROM orders)  
       )  `# of sales`
FROM (
  SELECT c_id, 
    COUNT(p_id) `# of p_ids`, 
    MIN(rating) `min rating`, 
    FORMAT(AVG(level), 2) `avg level`
  FROM stock
  GROUP BY c_id WITH ROLLUP
) t 
LEFT JOIN cats c ON c.c_id = t.c_id
LEFT JOIN stock s ON s.c_id = t.c_id
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.p_id = s.p_id
GROUP BY t.c_id, c.c_name, t.`# of p_ids`, t.`min rating`, t.`avg level` 
ORDER BY c.c_name IS NULL, c.c_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sE83io7jir8F6StQ3s692J/2).
Results:

```
| c_name | # of p_ids | min rating | avg level | # of sales |
| ------ | ---------- | ---------- | --------- | ---------- |
| Boat   | 4          | 29         | 692.47    | 13         |
| Plane  | 3          | 17         | 732.47    | 3          |
| Car    | 1          | 92         | 503.34    | 7          |
| Bike   | 2          | 19         | 154.04    | 6          |
|        | 10         | 17         | 577.87    | 29         |
```

Comment: This does work, thank you. Could you explain why coalesce is necessary to group the sales by category in the last column?

Comment: COALESCE() is needed only to provide the # of sales in the last row. This row initially contains NULL for the # of sales so it must be computed separately with a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result you want by using a couple of aggregations as table expressions; then you just join them together to produce the complete result.

For example:

```
select
  x.c_name,
  x.number_of_pids,
  x.min_rating,
  x.avg_level,
  s.sum_sales
from (
  select
    c.c_id,
    max(c.c_name) as c_name,
    count(distinct s.p_id) as number_of_pids,
    min(s.rating) as min_rating,
    avg(s.level) as avg_level
  from cats c
  left join stock s on s.c_id = c.c_id
  group by c.c_id
) x
left join (
  select
    s.c_id, sum(sales) as sum_sales
  from stock s
  left join orders o on o.p_id = s.p_id
  group by s.c_id
) s on s.c_id = x.c_id
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to do a rollup at the end as well? I tried putting WITH ROLLUP after the group by c.c_id line, but that doesn't do a total for sum_sales, because I assume it's outside the scope of that part of the query.